# Transactional e-mail: How to template 'sales_email_order_items' (or how to override adminhtml template)

Tags: magento-1.7, email, email-templates

In the transactional email code, I see this:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
{{var items_html}}
```

Which, I believe, refers to this template file:

`/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/email/order/items.phtml`

I've tried creating a new folder with our theme to avoid overwriting core files:

`/app/design/our_theme/default/default/template/email/order/items.phtml`

But this doesn't seem to work, is there a proper way to override this file without simply overwriting the core?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually it refers to a Layout XML handle you can find in the `sales.xml` file around line 268.

There you can find the following tags

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_items>
```

You can copy this to your own themes `local.xml` and edit whatever you need. In your case it would be resetting the template file like so:-

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <reference name="items">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>yourdirectory/order/items.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</sales_email_order_items>
```

Comment: Oops, you are totally right. Thank you! Will accept when possible :)

Comment: No problem, it can be somewhat confusing :)

Comment: @SanderMangel How can I create {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}} other than  default, which I will be using in the email templates(Other than order confirmation email template)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but you can call any handle from the local.xml from your email template. So you can create a new one if you want

Answer (score 6):

You can see which template "sales_email_order_items" refers when looking into

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/bundle.xml
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/downloadable.xml
```

In `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml` for example you will see:

```
<sales_email_order_items>
        <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                    <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
    </sales_email_order_items>
```

Here you can find out the path: `template="email/order/items.phtml"`

Your directory structure `/app/design/our_theme/default/default/template/email/order/items.phtml` seems wrong, especially the part `/app/design/our_theme/default/default/template...` - it should be `/app/design/our_theme/default/template...` (one default less, i guess).