# Programatically Sending Transactional Emails Doesn't Include Products

Tags: email, email-templates, transactional

When I send out my transactional email programatically, I'm not getting any items in a table like I do when the email is sent automatically.

Looking into the templates, the information is pulled across via:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

This is sending directive:

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode("More Information Required");
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email', Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()));
$emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name', Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()));
$emailTemplate->send($order->getCustomerEmail(), $order->getCustomerName(), [
    'order' => $order,
    'customer' => $order->getCustomerName(),
    'dateAndTime' => $order->getCreatedAt()
]);
```

All the data is filled correctly, except the order items grid. Nothing is displayed for this.

**Update**
To answer the question in the comments, the `$order` variable is generated as a result of an observer action on an event (in this case, `sales_order_save_after`). The variable that eventually becomes `$order` (when passed into a function) is formed as follows:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getData('data_object')
```

This contains a standard order object, of the following class: `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`

Comment: What do you get if you dump your $order var?

Comment: @mbalparda I've updated the question with your query in mind.

Comment: Do you have "{{var items_html}}" after "{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}"? Look here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/transactional-e-mail-how-to-template-sales-email-order-items-or-how-to-overr

Comment: I'm afraid that adding {{var items_html}} doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: In your call to `$emailTemplate->send`, is that pseudo-code? See your third argument. You can't construct an array in PHP with brackets like that (`[]`) - it would throw an exception.

Comment: @RickBuczynski PHP 5.4 added Short Syntax for Arrays - http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php this is not the issue as all the variables are currently being read successfully in the email, but the order items grid is not.

Comment: ahh, ok. Man I gotta keep up with the times :)

Comment: Is the header row for the items printed or is that also not visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a shot in the dark.
If you send e-mails from an "area agnostic" script then the `layout` directive does not know from where to load the handle `sales_email_order_items`.
Take a look at the `layoutDirective` method from the `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter` class. This is the class that parses and interprets the email templates:

```
    if (isset($params['area'])) {
        $layout->setArea($params['area']);
    }
    else {
        $layout->setArea(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getArea());
    }
```

In your case `$params['area']` is not set and you fall on the `else` case.
but here `Mage::app()->getLayout()->getArea()` most probably has no value.

You can try to change this

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

to this

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
```

or

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="adminhtml"}}
```

to see what happens.

Comment: I'm afraid neither frontend or adminhtml will work in my case. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @DanHanly. Sorry. Apparently I'm not that good at shooting in the dark. At least you have a place to start debugging. `layoutDirective` is the start point.

Comment: The 'area' point was a good one, though it wasn't appropriate to add the it into the layout handle declaration. Before I begin adding parameters to the order, I needed to add the following line - `$emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId]);` This meant that the email itself was configured to utilise a specific area. Your thought process led me to discover this answer, so thanks very much for that.

Comment: @DanHanly. AHA. I knew it was something about the area. Nice call on the the `setDesignConfig`. I learned something from this question also :).

Comment: I've assigned to bounty to you, otherwise it'd go to waste. You did give me some hugely influential information to fix the issue, so I do feel it's deserved :)

Comment: @DanHanly. Thanks. But I feel a little bad that I didn't give a right answer. I feel like I don't really deserve the full bounty. :)