# Change 1.9 rwd new order e-mail template item tabel

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, rwd-theme, order-email

How or where can i change the rwd item tabel, from the **order e-mail template**? At the bottom of the e-mail. It don't look good at the moment. It looks like there are missing some styles? See attachment.

[image]

**-------UPDATE--------**

Ok now i try to get it back like non-rwd versions before (overriding some files from /base/). I am almost there have a look at the image below. The `[footer]` is outside of the table and the `totals` are not aligned to the right?

[image]

What am i missing?

Comment: can you show the html for that email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. In Magento 1.9 RWD they added `/app/design/frontend/meez-package/meez-theme/template/email/order/totals/wrapper.phtml`. In this file i removed some HTML. `wrapper.phtml` looks like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

Now its looking better:

[image]

Comment: What html did you remove? I have this same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Magento sales email order item are comming from

```
app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOUR_TEMPLATE/template/email/order/items.phtml
```

**OR**

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml
```

### All sales email related templates file are located at

```
app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOUR_TEMPLATE/template/email/
```

**OR**

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/
```

**[Update]**

Magento all sales relate template exits at

```
app/locale/YOUR_LANGUAGE/template/email/sales
```

and `order_new.html,order_new_guest.html`  are responsible for new order  templa

Comment: i followed your logic. I update my question above. Do you know what i am missing?

Comment: I copied the order item template into my theme folder and made some changes. Still, email templates are loading from base/default/template/email/order/item.phtml

Comment: Also I tried https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/transactional-e-mail-how-to-template-sales-email-order-items-or-how-to-overr too.. but no luck, Can you suggest here