# Where Can I edit the Order totals table in Magento OrderEmails

Tags: magento-1.9

Can you please help me to find where order totals table added and how to edit the totals table in the order emails.

I need to edit the discount word in the following image when a shopping cart rule applied.

[image: Order email table]

Comment: This one will help for you, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62505/change-1-9-rwd-new-order-e-mail-template-item-tabel

Answer (score 0):

I found the file it is here:
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml

Thanks